# Accessing Custom Collection Items by Key

Tags: class, vba, collections, key

I have defined a class to store requirements information. It contains a unique req-key.

```
    Option Explicit

    Private pKey As String
    Private pName As String
    Private pReqRef As New clsReqCollection
    Private pReqType As RequirementType
    Private pProblem As String

    Public Enum RequirementType
       Ziel = 0
       Fachanforderung = 1
       Produktanforderung = 2
       Prozessanforderung = 3
       Organisationsanforderung = 4
       ITAnforderung = 5
       Datenanforderung = 6
       RandUndRahmenbedingung = 7
    End Enum
    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Key property
    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    Public Property Get Key() As String
        Key = pKey
    End Property
    Public Property Let Key(Value As String)
        pKey = Value
    End Property
    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Name property
    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    Public Property Get Name() As String
        Name = pName
    End Property
    Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
        pName = Value
    End Property
    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' ReqRef property
    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    Public Property Get ReqRef() As clsReqCollection
        ReqRef = pReqRef
    End Property
    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' ReqType property
    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    Public Property Get ReqType() As RequirementType
       ReqType = pReqType
    End Property
    Public Property Let ReqType(Value As RequirementType)
        pReqType = Value
    End Property
    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Problem property
    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    Public Property Get Problem() As String
        Problem = pProblem
    End Property
    Public Property Let Problem(Value As String)
        pProblem = Value
    End Property
```

Now I build a custom collection to store requirements objects as follows

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "clsReqCollection"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private requirements As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   Set requirements = New Collection
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
   Set requirements = Nothing   
End Sub

Public Function NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
Attribute NewEnum.VB_MemberFlags = "40"
    Set NewEnum = requirements.[_NewEnum]
End Function

Public Sub Add(aRequirement As clsRequirement)
   requirements.Add aRequirement, aRequirement.Key
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(cIndex As Variant)
   requirements.Remove cIndex
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(cIndex As Variant) As clsRequirement
   Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0
   Set Item = requirements.Item(cIndex)
End Property

Public Property Get Count() As Integer
   Count = requirements.Count
End Property

Public Sub Clear()
   Set requirements = New Collection
End Sub
```

As I add the objekts using the in the object stored key, I hoped to be able to access the custom collection also by supplying the key:

```
Dim reqs As New clsReqCollection
Dim currReq As clsRequirement

Set currReq = New clsRequirement
currReq.Key = "Key"
currReq.Name = "Name"

reqs.Add currReq
Debug.Print reqs.Item("Key").Name
```

Somehow the last line does not work, I get a runtime error '5'. Any idea what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Dim reqs As New clsReqCollection
Dim currReq As clsRequirement

Set currReq = New clsRequirement
currReq.Key = "Key"
currReq.Name = "Name"

reqs.Add currReq, "Key"

Debug.Print reqs.Item("Key").Name
```

See [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265006%28v=vs.60%29.aspx):

The user defined .Key is not taken into account, this is only a normal member of your class. Only internal collection key can be used as hash table like key to fetch item.